# object files in git

Tags: git, c++

I am using a git repository which contains a lot of sources (10.000 cpp files). Compiling the project takes around an hour. The resulting *.o files are generated in the **build** directory. This directory is in *.gitignore* and excluded. When switching a branch, I would like to temporarily move these object files, because I don't want to recompile when I switch back to it. What is the common way to tackle this problem?

```
master
 -  .gitignore
 -  build/
 -  src/
```

Comment: Why does a branch switch cause a full recompile, anyway? Is it that your branches touch some "core" files that every single .o depends on?

Comment: Yes exactly. It’s not a full rebuild but it takes long enough, depending on the Branch

Answer (score 1):

Check out your branches somewhere else, using [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree):

```
git worktree add <new_path> <branch>
```

Comment: Thanks! Does worktree need to be supported by IDEs? Or do they all support it?

Comment: It probably needs to be supported by IDEs (but it depends on how deep the IDE is trying to dig into Git's internals)... and just the fact that the new worktree is at a different path means the IDE will see it as a different project, too.